# Failing the Notebook by Raising a custom Exception in Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have a simple conditional logic to implement in pyspark.
When condition is true should continue the execution if it is false then the notebook should fail with appropriate error
Here is the code

```
response = opener.open(url, data)
resp = response.read().decode('utf-8')
if str in resp:
    print("yes continue execution")
else:
    print("No, Notebook should fail")
```

Tried raising a custom exception and is not working.
Please Advise

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you try `raise Exception("message here")`?

Comment: Yes, I did that and it failed with Invalid "Exception" not defined